# Convert json object to recordset?

Tags: json, postgresql, type-conversion

Using Postgres 11, how can I convert this JSON object (with a text index and integers as values)

```
{"a":{"col1":1,"col2":2,"col3":3}
,"b":{"col1":4,"col2":5,"col3":6}
,"c":{"col1":7,"col2":8,"col3":9}}
```

to a recordset like:

```
r_id | col1 | col2 | col3
-------------------------
   a |    1 |    2 |    3
   b |    4 |    5 |    6
   c |    7 |    8 |    9
```

Comment: Your version of Postgres? Exact source and target data types? Is there a table, view or similar with that exact target row type?

Comment: Updated with version, and target data types. There is no table, view or similar with that row type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288589/939860) seems good enough for just three value columns.

With more columns, [`json_populate_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) would shorten the syntax and make it a bit faster. It builds on a template row type, though, which you do not have. You can easily provide it by creating a temporary table (visible inside the session until the end of the session):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

SELECT key AS r_id, (json_populate_record(null::t1, value)).*
FROM json_each('{"a":{"col1":1,"col2":2,"col3":3}
               , "b":{"col1":4,"col2":5,"col3":6}
               , "c":{"col1":7,"col2":8,"col3":9}}')
```

If your JSON document was an array of records, you could use `json_populate_recordset()`:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t2(r_id text, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

SELECT *
FROM   json_populate_recordset(null::t2
             , '[{"r_id":"a","col1":1,"col2":2,"col3":3}
               , {"r_id":"b","col1":4,"col2":5,"col3":6}
               , {"r_id":"c","col1":7,"col2":8,"col3":9}]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT key AS r_id, value->>'col1' AS col1, value->>'col2' AS col2, value->>'col3' AS col3
FROM JSON_EACH('{"a":{"col1":1,"col2":2,"col3":3},"b":{"col1":4,"col2":5,"col3":6},"c":{"col1":7,"col2":8,"col3":9}}');
```